# How to get the the multidimensional array in single column

Tags: php

Here is my array which i want in single column with key.

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [9] =>                  $2y$10$eP7dUFBqeCZItMg2A8cSFufAi7UC0OfKjzfpkohOAD/lHBsoM6tFu
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [76] => $2y$10$DZn/JI0.2HV6DHA9CfEWZ.9MoNNkIKozTURcA5vOTVUE8O8uaBF3.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [7] => $2y$10$gSAtgpFVjhcMk2CAaLOuvOle3dkNqltZOu1I.0NzxOJT/COnu8evq
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [82] => $2y$10$B9vG6uBHY004Xn0s2TGkkuRJfuE1wlNqmuQno5ZWqjlwbObMohH5O
        )
```

I need this array in single column lik

```
Array(

     [9]=> $2y$10$eP7dUFBqeCZItMg2A8cSFufAi7UC0OfKjzfpkohOAD/lHBsoM6tFu
     [76]=> $2y$10$DZn/JI0.2HV6DHA9CfEWZ.9MoNNkIKozTURcA5vOTVUE8O8uaBF3.
     [7]=>$2y$10$gSAtgpFVjhcMk2CAaLOuvOle3dkNqltZOu1I.0NzxOJT/COnu8evq
     [82]=> $2y$10$B9vG6uBHY004Xn0s2TGkkuRJfuE1wlNqmuQno5ZWqjlwbObMohH5O
    )
```

I try to flatten array but it not show 0,1,2,3 keys in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$newArray` has what you are looking for.

```
$newArray = array(); 
 foreach($arrayData as $valueArray){
   foreach($valueArray as $key=>$value){
    $newArray[$key]= $value;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same with single foreach also using `key` and `current`.

```
$res = [];
foreach($array as $v){
  $res[key($v)] = current($v); 
}
```